# Has anyone used RemoteWipe in Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile

I just got my Treo and noting the lack of a software reset (the need to use the stylus on the reset button really annoys me), I decided to build my own.

The Reset and Suspend part of my little program works like a charm and then I decided to improve a little more and add a Hard Reset feature, which would restore the device to its factory settings.

Searching high and low on the net I found two possible ways. The first one involved calling `SetCleanRebootFlag()` and then reset the device.

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern void SetCleanRebootFlag();

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern int SetSystemPowerState(IntPtr psState, PowerStateFlags flags, uint Options);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern bool KernelIoControl(int dwIoControlCode, IntPtr inBuf, int inBufSize, IntPtr outBuf, int outBufSize, ref int bytesReturned);

public static void SoftReset()
{
    if (SetSystemPowerState(IntPtr.Zero, PowerStateFlags.Reset, 0x1000) != 0)
    {
        int bytesReturned = 0;
        if (!KernelIoControl(0x101003c, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref bytesReturned))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
    }
}

public static void HardReset()
{
    SetCleanRebootFlag();
    SoftReset();
}
```

The other involved using the `ConfigurationManager` to process a XML that would perform a "RemoteWipe".

```
public static void HardReset()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<wap-provisioningdoc>" + 
                    "<characteristic type='RemoteWipe'>" + 
                        "<parm name='doWipe' value='1'/>" +
                    "</characteristic>" +
                "</wap-provisioningdoc>");
    ConfigurationManager.ProcessConfiguration(doc, true);
}
```

The first method didn't work because after Windows Mobile 5 it ignores the `CleanBootFlag`; the second method worked... too much.

It corrupted the microSD on the device to the point that it needed to be reformatted in order to be recognized again.

Does anyone had any experience with that?

---

**Edited to add**: 
Unfortunately the answer to my question is exactly like [Paul Betts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5728/paul-betts) said. To quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737595.aspx)

> > The RemoteWipe Configuration Service Provider enables mobile operators to remotely wipe a device. RemoteWipe Configuration Service Provider will make the data stored in **memory, storage cards, and hard disks** difficult to recover if the device is remotely wiped after being lost or stolen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this what [Remote Wipe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998614.aspx) is supposed to do?